# how to create dynamic scripts from a script using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, function, seo, json-ld

I have a script where I am using Jquery foreach loop to fetch data, every thing is working good now I want to create a JSON-LD data for google to read it.

so I want to create a script and pass my values that comes from loop in that json script to create these scripts dynamic.

Also my scripts will visible when I open to see "view-source" of my page.

I have used some scripts but they didn't work for me.
Can any one suggest how to do that??

Comment: What do you mean by "my scripts will be visible in view-source"?   Do you mean that the script you wrote is visible there or that you want the dynamic script to be visible there?

Comment: I want dynamic script to be visible there..

Comment: That isn't going to be possible. View source it's what you were server returns. JQuery runs client side.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.